# UK child visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, india, children

My 16-month-old son got his visitor visa, which states that he has to be accompanied by his mother. That's fine.

But, due to some reason, my wife won't be able to return with him as her official stay was extended.

In this case, can I (father) return with my child (without the mother) back to India though my name is not endorsed on my son's visa? Will there be any issue or violation of rules?

Answer (score 1):

Your child was granted a UK Standard Visit visa, with the proviso that he be accompanied as he is a minor (under 18), in this case by his mother. She agreed to this condition when the visa was issued (and the visa does allow for both parents to be named; why were you not included?).

The [UK does have exit checks](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/exit-checks-on-passengers-leaving-the-uk/exit-checks-fact-sheet) on all passengers leaving the country, through passenger records and predominately used for immigration and data purposes. Your departures (for you, your son, and your wife) will be reflected in your immigration records, and it will show that the child entered with his mother, and left with someone else.

As your plans constitute a material change to your son’s visa, it may be best to [Report a change of circumstances if you have a visa or BRP](https://www.gov.uk/change-circumstances-visa-brp).

And should you leave with your child and not encounter any issues doing so, depending on circumstances, it could affect future visa applications, for both you and your wife. It could be viewed as a serious breach of visa conditions, which the UK does not look upon very kindly.

Comment: And that the OP should have also added his name on the visa in the hindsight. It doesn’t cost 1 penny more and it’s almost foolish to request only one name when both parents are happily together and are traveling with the child. Why on earth did the OP not request his name to also be there on the Visa?

Comment: @HankyPanky so agree and, without too much speculation, that may be the very reason he should not attempt to take the child from the UK; it could trigger very serious consequences... the UK is hyper-vigilant when it comes to children.